# Deploy DLL automatically on build

Tags: c#, .net, build, nuget, geckofx

I'm using [nuget GeckoFX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeckoFX/) for a project.

After installing this package, I've noticed that it contains only two .NET DLL referenced to my project (`Geckofx-Core` and `Geckofx-Winforms`).

I've noticed also that the nuget installer did not put any build events on my project.

But every time I build the project, it generates many other dlls and exe in the Debug directory.

How could it do that?

Comment: if automatically add references when you add nuget packages and set "Copy Local" = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeckoFX NuGet package depends on the [Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output/) which is the NuGet package that is responsible for copying the files to your output directory.

The [Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output](https://github.com/baseclass/Contrib.Nuget) NuGet package has a custom MSBuild task that looks for an output directory that any installed NuGet package has and will copy all those files to your project's output directory.

If you look in your packages directory you will see that the GeckoFX NuGet package has an output directory:

```
packages\GeckoFX.1.0.4\output
```

All these files are copied to your project's output directory when your project is compiled.